# How do i connect the Trezor emulator to Monero GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, trezor

I have set up the trezor suite and also the trezor user environment(emulator) but now i am having trouble figuring out how can i emulate the monero gui. Any tips or steps will be greatly appreciated.